# Unordered Dictionary in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I would like to iterate through the key of an unordered dictionary in Javascript. I don't even know if it does exist or not.

At the moment I am having the following code :

```
var l = [5,3,2];
var unorderedDict = {};
for (var i=0; i<l.length; i++) {
    unorderedDict[l[i]] = 'foo';
}
```

My dictionary will then be like : `{2:'foo', 3:'foo', 5:'foo'}` or in my case, I would like to keep the ordering of the initial list (so : `{5:'foo', 3:'foo', 2:'foo'}`)

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Why do you want to keep the order in the object? BTW it is not possible. Is there any specific reason?

Comment: I am just wondering either this is possible or not.

Comment: @user1058398 Nope, its not possible. Sounds like XY problem to me. What are you actually trying to do

Comment: Take a look at this one too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot maintain order in `object`. If you want to maintain order use array:

```js
var l = [5, 3, 2];
var val = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
var unorderedDict = [];
//                  ^^
for (var i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
  unorderedDict[l[i]] = val[i];
}

// Iterate over array:
for (var i = 0; i < unorderedDict.length; i++) {
  if (unorderedDict[i]) {
    console.log(unorderedDict[i]);
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want the order to be the same as shown in `l`:

```
// Iterate over array:
for (var i=0; i<l.length; i++) {
    console.log(unorderedDict[l[i]]);
}
```

Comment: This is not correct. It will create new hash table. Order not preserved. I made a runnable snippet as edit and it proves that wrong.

Comment: @RuslanasBalčiūnas It does preserve order, since it is an `array`

Comment: My bad, it is array with undefined missing values. But still this solution does not preserve order in `l`. You need a different data structure to accomplish that.

Comment: Or using the `l` to get the sequence